# Could not resolve host: mirrorlist.centos.org; unknown error

Tags: networking, centos7

I'm very new to all of this, so forgive me if this is a common problem with a common answer. I've looked all around and can't find a solution to this problem. I've just installed CentOS 7 and decided to run `yum update` to make sure all of my stuff is up to date and get an error. I've tried to `ping 8.8.8.8` as well as ping `192.168.0.1` and both times it tells me the network is unreachable. When viewing `/etc/resolv.conf`, it is populated, with 2 nameservers as well as `search tds`, so it's not as if it hasn't been populated. I wonder if it's some sort of problem with my network configuration. `ip route` is completely empty, and running `nmcli d` shows that I currently don't have a connection to the wifi card, Ethernet, or loopback. Interestingly enough, my wifi card `wlp2s0` doesn't show up in `etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` at all.

Edit: Plugging the Ethernet in and setting `onboot` to yes fixes this problem. However, I forgot to mention that I'm doing this on a laptop. If it's possible, I'd rather be able to connect through wifi.

Comment: `I currently don't have a connection to the wifi card, Ethernet, or loopback` this should be the first thing to investigate.

Comment: I agree with @GeraldSchneider - plug the machine in with an ethernet cable to get started, not all wifi cards are equal in the Linux world!

Comment: Great that you were able to solve it. But please don't edit your solution into the question, post your answer instead and accept it when you are allowed to do so. Otherwise the question will stay as unsolved in the system forever and pop up again and again. It's perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some more digging around, I found that I needed to connect to the internet via Ethernet and `yum install NetworkManager-wifi`. After installing the wifi package, I connected to it by checking the wifi list with `nmcli dev wifi list` and then using `nmcli --ask dev wifi connect <wifi name>` properly connected to it.